# Javascript: Add +1 to number that starts with 0 (like 01, 02, 03) and keep the zero

Tags: javascript, math, addition

I like to add (+1) to a number. But problem is my number can sometimes have 0 preceding it. Like 01, 02, 03, 04. So I like result to be:

```
mockup01 + 1 = mockup02
mockup11 + 1 = mockup12
```

How can that be achieved? Example of how I would use it would be if I had filename named **mockup_01.htm** and change it to **mockup_02.htm**

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe this

```
 next = (parseInt(number, 10) + 101).toString().substr(1)
```

to make a mockup_02.htm out of mockup_01 try this

```
newName = fileName.replace(/\d+(?=\.)/, function(n) {
    return (parseInt(n, 10) + Math.pow(10, n.length) + 1).toString().substr(1)
});
```

this works with numbers of any length, e.g. mockup_0001, mockup_000001 etc

Comment: +1 for remembering the , 10.  Otherwise, it will parse numbers starting with 0 as octals ("031" would become 25).

Comment: Wondering if you know how it would work if I wanted to include the entire string... like

mockup_01.htm to mockup02.htm

Comment: hey thanks a lot!! tried to give you another (+) for answer but think it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a javascript programmer, but it seems like you're mixing up presentation and internal representation.  If the "01" is a string, with a corresponding integer variable, you can convert from the string to the integer, add 1, and then make a new string with the desired formatting.  This is sometimes referred to as a model-view-controller pattern.  The model is the integer variable - it models the internal behavior of numbers.  The view is the string - it presents the number in a human readable fashion.  The controller handles the numerical operations.

Comment: No offense, but MVC isn't for everything. I think you are over-architecting the problem.

Comment: @chakrit - You're right.  I mean MVC just as a model for thinking, not actually connecting up the handlers and callback for every little variable.  But stereofrog's (very good) answer handles the representation->data->representation changes in one line.  It's important to realize all those changes are necessary to solve the problem, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
function next_id(input) {
  var output = parseInt(input, 10)+1; // parse and increment
  output += ""; // convert to string
  while (output.length<2) output = "0"+output; // prepend leading zeros
  return output;
}

var id = "00";
for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
  console.log(id);
  id = next_id(id);
}
```

Comment: +1 - Could make it a little more reusable by getting the `var desiredLength=(''+input).length`  then doing `while (output.length<desiredLength)`  So it would work with `01` or `007` ;)